# How to get the category of Issues Root Causes on Forge BIM 360 API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I wanna get the categories of root causes, and also know if a root cause is active or not.

This is configured on the Project `Admin/Issues/Services/Root Causes` session on the BIM 360.

[image]

I try to get the root causes using the API `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/issues/v1/containers/:container_id/root-causes` documented at https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/root-causes-GET/.

But the response for this API doesn't tell what the category for the root cause, neither if it is active or not.

Here is a sample of the response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "5502171c-9e38-427e-a49a-40fa6821dec4",
      "type": "root_causes",
      "links": {
        "self": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/issues/v1/containers/be00f32e-c03c-4c7b-9ec4-d2614bf1980cu2n/root-causes/5502171c-9e38-427e-a49a-40fa6821dec4"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "key": "INSTALLATION",
        "title": "Installation"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "a3311fc6-4571-4fca-9fb4-37120d976bd2",
      "type": "root_causes",
      "links": {
        "self": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/issues/v1/containers/be00f32e-c03c-4c7b-9ec4-d2614bf1980cu2n/root-causes/a3311fc6-4571-4fca-9fb4-37120d976bd2"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "key": "WEATHER",
        "title": "Weather"
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I discover the category and the activation status of the issue's root cause by API?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a wish with getting root cause category. We have logged the internal ticket with engineer team: SCCOM-6392.

Some APIs are on the internal pipelines, but have not been yet exposed for public. As I know that endpoint Anderson is using has not been public. I will need to check with engineer team further. will update with you when I get any information.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I got the reply from engineer team, the endpoint Anderson is using are not exposed formally. you will use on your own risk. I have appended your request in the wish ticket: SCCOM-6392. your patience is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I managed to solve it as follows, I made a request to the URL [https://developer.api.autodesk.com/issues/v2/containers/[containerId]/issue-root-cause-categories?include=rootcauses&limit=9999](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/issues/v2/containers/%5BcontainerId%5D/issue-root-cause-categories?include=rootcauses&limit=9999) and then I scroll through the data and apply the filters I needed, I tried to pass some queryString but without success, so I decided to scroll through the data and filter there, I hope I have helped you.